# How to keep background transparent when presentViewController in iPhone?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I want to keep background transparent like UIActivityController in iPhone iOS6
[image]

I try to clear color and opaque but background always black like this (iPhone iOS5 simulator)

[image]

This is presentViewController code:

```
    ShareViewController *controller = [[ShareViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShareViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Activity complete");
    }];
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You need to add this Controller's view as a subview on to another view.

Comment: The background is black because after a presentViewController completes, the presenting controller's view is removed from the window's view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what you have to do is add a `UIView` behind the custom `UIActionsheet` you mentioned. Here what you can do is keep the Background-color of the `UIView` as white and then keep its alpha = 0.5.

When you dismiss the `UIActionsheet` you can `removeFromSuperview` the `UIView` added behind too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of presentViewController use [UIView transitionWithView] to define your custom animation.

- Start by having your view controller retained somewhere. (If you are using ARC have it as property on the parent view controller).
- Add the view controller's view as a subview to the current VC's view. Set the frame to be CGRectMake(0, screenBottom, screenWidth, screenHeight / 2);
- Animate by changing the frame so that it slides onto the screen.

  ```
  [UIView transitionWithView:<#(UIView *)view#> duration:0.5 options:nil
    animations:^
    {
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight / 2, screenWidth, screenHeight/ 2);
    } completion:nil];
  ```